# Is it possible to authenticate my credentials through console when the app starts?

Tags: javascript, authentication, console

I'm setting up a simple "fire and forget" kind of back-end app running on a DigitalOcean droplet. I want to start the app, enter a username and password into the console, and reuse that username and password later without entering data. Essentially, the app simply monitors various GitHub repositories for pull requests, reads comments and checks for "yes" or "no" votes from contributors, and then merges or closes that pull request based on majority vote.

The issue I have right now is that because the app has no UI, I can't figure out how to request a username and password from the user.

Ideally, I'd like to open the console, run the app, and then the first thing the app does is ask for a username and password in the console. It would then simply use the entered data as a variable for authentication later on down the line.

This is my very first time dealing with authentication (I'm about 3 months into JS programming). Any help is appreciated.

```js
const loginUsername = ()=> {
    //ask for username in this function
    return username;
};
const loginPassword = ()=> {
    //ask for password in this function
    return password;
};
```

Later on in the app:

```js
if(votesYes >= majorityVotes){
   console.log('The request has been accepted.')
   axios({
      method: 'put',
      url: `${pullRequestUrl}/${pull.number}/merge`,
      auth: {
         username: loginUsername,
         password: loginPassword
      }
})
```

As it stands right now, if I manually type in my username and password into the code, it all works swimmingly. But, given that the repo is public, I'd like to not include that data in the code.

Comment: You should use OAuth and the GitHub API.

Comment: The more I dig into that, though, it seems like I need to use the client ID and secret key in the .js file. That seems to be essentially the same problem as before--I don't want to have confidential information in the .js file directly. If that is my only option, I'll take that route.

Comment: Are you asking how to read a string from the console?

Comment: I don't know if what I want is possible (sorry, I'm really new to trying to authenticate apps). I want to login to the droplet console, start the app, and have the app send me a request to type in my username and password (similar to how it asks for my github credentials whenever I try working with private repositories).

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=nodejs+read+from+console

Comment: That looks like a very promising set of google results. Thanks--I just couldn't seem to word the question right in my searches. Appreciate your help!